# How to programmatically put data to the Google Appengine database from remote executable?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I would like to pre-fill and periodically put data to the Google Appengine database.

I would like to write a program in java and python that connect to my GAE service and upload data to my database.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use RemoteAPI for doing this programmatically.

In python, you can first configure the appengine_console.py as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html)

Once you have that, you can launch and write the following commands in the python shell:

$ python appengine_console.py yourapp

```
>>> import yourdbmodelclassnamehere
>>> m = yourmodelclassnamehere(x='',y='')
>>> m.put()
```

And here is code from the java version which is self explanatory (directly borrowed from the [remote api page on gae docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html)):

```
package remoteapiexample;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller;
import com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RemoteApiExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String username = System.console().readLine("username: ");
        String password = 
            new String(System.console().readPassword("password: "));
        RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions()
            .server("<your app>.appspot.com", 443)
            .credentials(username, password);
        RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
        installer.install(options);
        try {
            DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
            System.out.println("Key of new entity is " + 
                ds.put(new Entity("Hello Remote API!")));
        } finally {
            installer.uninstall();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably give him the [Java version](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html).

Comment: Please name the API and add the java version to your answer before I accept it. This is the java version : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi.html

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the "culture" of StackOverflow, but the question asked for code in "java **or** python" not "java **and** python". Saying you won't accept the answer until they add the Java version seems unfair to me.

Comment: @djondal: editing the question is pretty silly; why would you *want* to write the same program in both?

Comment: I have not decided what language i'll use just to fill the database. I'm just playing with the tools.